# Running Flask app in Docker giving "can’t establish a connection" error?

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose

I'm trying to access the flask webpage on my host machine. I've tried two different methods to make this work. However, for both methods I get `can’t establish a connection to the server at localhost:5000`. I've tried accessing from `0.0.0.0:5000`, `localhost:5000`, and `127.0.0.1` but none work.

1. Running directly from the `web` directory.

   `docker build --tag my-python-app .
   docker run --name python-app -p 5000:5000 my-python-app`
2. Running `docker-compose` from the `flask-compose-sample` directory.

   `docker-compose up --build`

Directory structure:

```
flask-compose-sample
  - web
    - app.py
    - Dockerfile
    - requirements.txt
  - docker-compose.yml
```

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Welcome to the Data Science Learner!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=int("5000"), debug=True)
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:alpine3.7
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 5000
CMD python app.py
```

**requirements.txt**

`flask==0.10.1`

**docker-compose.yml**

```
web:
  build: ./web
  ports:
   - "5000:5000"
  volumes:
   - .:/code
```

Comment: dockerfile and compose file seems fine, are you using docker-toolbox? try to debug `docker exec -it  python-app  sh -c "apk add --no-cache curl && sleep 1 && curl localhost:5000"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer. I didn't find this answer on the many other posts I searched on either so hopefully it helps someone else.

If you're using Docker Quickstart Terminal like I am, it doesn't use the localhost IP. Instead it has it's own IP of `192.168.99.100`. Using that instead of `localhost` makes everything work.